# line 1:0 no viable alternative at character 'H' exception

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, web-services, web-client

i was trying to create a client server web api where the client calls a web-service say web1 and then web1 becomes a client of another web service say web2. web2 returns to web1 and thus the client executes. **my aim is to create a web services composition and print the result as a submission of both web services.**

while doing this i encountered this error:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at character 'H' 
line 1:1 no viable alternative at character 'e' 
line 1:2 no viable alternative at character 'l'
line 1:3 no viable alternative at character 'l'
line 1:4 no viable alternative at character 'o'
line 1:5 no viable alternative at character 'p'
line 1:6 no viable alternative at character 'r'
line 1:7 no viable alternative at character 'i'
line 1:8 no viable alternative at character 'y'
line 1:9 no viable alternative at character 'a'
line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad 
Request
```

here 'hello' is the message that should run when i call *getMessage()* and 'priya' is name called on *getName()*

the code was:

//client

```
public class MessageClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client= ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget baseTarget = 
    client.target("http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi");
    WebTarget messageTarget = baseTarget.path("messages");
    WebTarget singleMsgTarget = messageTarget.path("{messageId}");

    Message message1= singleMsgTarget
            .resolveTemplate("messageId", "1")
            .request()
            .get(Message.class);

    System.out.println(message1.getMessage());
}
}
```

//web1 (which is client of web2)

```
 @Path("/messages")
public class MessageResources {
MessageService ms = new MessageService();

@GET
@Path("{messageId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id)
{

Client client= ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget baseTarget= 
client.target("http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi");
    WebTarget infoTarget= baseTarget.path("/info");
    WebTarget singleInfoTarget= infoTarget.path("{infoId}");

    InfoCreated info= singleInfoTarget
            .resolveTemplate("infoId", "1")
            .request()
            .get(InfoCreated.class);
    String name = info.getName();

    Message message = ms.getMessage(id);

    String msg=message.getMessage();

    String result = msg.concat(name);

    return result;
}
```

there is no error in the code, but the error appears at runtime.